# Ruby: Variable passed to function gets changed

Tags: ruby, string, function

Why is the variable `var` passed to a function in the following code changed after the function has been executed?

```
def my_func(my_var)
  out_var = my_var
  out_var[3]="STUFF"
  return out_var
end

var = "Testing"
puts my_func(var)
puts var
```

Output:

```
TesSTUFFing
TesSTUFFing
```

Why has "var" been changed? Can someone please explain this to me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Ruby variables are passed by reference.

You have to explicitly clone the variable:

```
def my_func(my_var)
  out_var = my_var.clone
  out_var[3]="STUFF"
  out_var
end
```

Comment: Thanks! Just what I needed to know.

Answer (score 2):

Strings are not immutable in Ruby, so you can pass a string to a function that modifies the string.